# Junit3 suite.addTest(new mytest()) get 'null' error

Tags: junit, junit3

I create a test suite and want to add some new tests, but suite.addTest() method seems doesn't work as I expected:

```
public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(AllTests.class.getName());
    //$JUnit-BEGIN$
    // This line works
    suite.addTestSuite(TestAdd.class);
    // This line will cause a 'null' failure
    suite.addTest(new TestAdd());
    //$JUnit-END$
    return suite;
}
```

Code of TestAdd:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class TestAdd extends TestCase { 
    public void test1()
    {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: Please post your code for TestAdd. It could be the constructor causing the problem. Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with TestAdd class. It's a trivial one.

Comment: Can you also post the full error and stack trace that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadocs:

> **TestCase()**
>
> No-arg constructor to enable serialization. *This method is not intended to be used by mere mortals without calling setName().*
>
> **TestCase(java.lang.String name)**
>
> Constructs a test case with the given name.

It appears you must use the TestCase constructor passing the test a name string. Using the no-arg constructor is intended to enable serialization of the test cases only.

Try:

```
suite.addTest(new TestAdd("add"));
```

Comment: Thanks. suite.addTest(new TestAdd("add")) doesn't work, it failed with:
[junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Method "add" not found]                             
    suite.addTest(new TestAdd("test1")) works.
The string parameter must be a method of TestAdd class, but that's not what I expected...

Comment: Work out with adding a new constructor[ public TestAdd(String methodName, <other_args>). Thank you!